# Один тест для нескольких классов

Tags: java, junit

Есть тест на jUnit и несколько идентичных методов. Допустим, методы Mock и Stub.
Как параметрически производить переключение на тестирование то одного, то другого метода?

Comment: чтот значит параметрически? с использованием дополнительного параметра?

Comment: Я сам до конца не понимаю как это может быть реализовано. Либо аннотация, либо вызов теста с параметром, либо ещё что...
Суть в том, что должна быть возможность динамически выбирать класс, на который будет натравливаться тест.

Comment: ну тогда лучше всего задавать через environment или в каком-то конфигурационном файле. а еще лучше сделать 2 разных теста

Comment: 2 разных точно не вариант. Задача стоит именно 1 тест на все реализации, что, собственно логично. Зачем плодить то?..

Comment: Плодить тесты - это как раз более оправданный подход, т.к. максимально изолирует тестируемую функциональнсоть. А вот плодить идентичные методы не стоит.

Answer (score 2):

вариант с простым переключением:
    class MockStubTest extends Test {

```
private boolean stub = false;
protected MockStubTest (boolean stub) {
 this.stub = stub
}

public void test() {
   if (stub) {stub();} else { mock() ;}
 }

}

class MockTest extends MockStubTest {
 public MockTest () {
   super(false);
 }
}

class StubTest extends MockStubTest {
 public MockTest () {
   super(true);
 }
}
```

если нужно проверять разные реализации одного и того же интерфейса:

```
class ListTest extends Test
{

    public void test()
    {
        List<?> list = createList();

        // тест непосредственно

    }

    protected abstract List<?> createList();

}

class ArrayListTest extends ListTest
{
    protected List<?> createList()
    {
    return new ArrayedList();
    }
}

class LinkedListTest extends ListTest
{
    protected List<?> createList()
    {
    return new LinkedList();
    }
}
```

нет ничего страшного в том чтоб создать 2-3 класса. ведь вполне вероятно что со временем в одной из реализаций появится какой-то метод который тоже надо будет проверить. но ваш "конфигурируемый универсальный мега-тест" уже не справится с такой задачей, - придется придумывать велосипед и прикручивать "костыли"

**UPDATE**: поправил чтоб в ответе были оба примера

Comment: Спасибо! Рассматривал такой вариант, но думал, что может быть существует решение проще.
Говорят, в пару строк кода проблема решается.